# structured streaming - explode json fields into dynamic columns?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I got this dataframe from a Kafka source.

```
+-----------------------+
|         data          |
+-----------------------+
| '{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }'  |
+-----------------------+
| '{ "b": 3, "d": 4 }'  |
+-----------------------+
| '{ "a": 2, "c": 4 }'  |
+-----------------------+
```

I want to transform this into the following data frame:

```
+---------------------------+
|  a   |  b   |  c   |  d   |
+---------------------------+
|  1   |  2   | null | null |
+---------------------------+
| null |  3   | null |  4   |
+---------------------------+
|  2   | null |  4   | null |
+---------------------------+
```

Number of JSON fields may change, so I couldn’t specify a schema for it.

I pretty much got the idea how to do the transformation in spark batch, by using some map and reduce to get a set of JSON keys, then construct new dataframe by using `withColumns`.

However as far as I've been exploring, there is no map reduce function in structured streaming. How do I achieve this?

**UPDATE**

I figured out UDF can be utilized to parse string to JSON fields

```py
import simplejson as json
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def convert_json(s):
   return json.loads(s)

udf_convert_json = udf(convert_json, StructType(<..some schema here..>))
df = df.withColumn('parsed_data', udf_convert_json(df.data))
```

However since the schema is dynamic I need to get all JSON keys and values existed in `df.data` for a certain window period to construct a StructType used in udf return type.

In the end, I guess I need to know how to perform a `reduce` in dataset for a certain window period then use it as a lookup schema in stream transformation.

Comment: Consider using `transform` with streaming to get your missing functions.

Comment: I think that one is for DStream API

Answer (score 1):

If you already know all unique keys in your json data, then we can use json_tuple function,

```
>>> df.show()
+------------------+
|              data|
+------------------+
|{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }|
|{ "b": 3, "d": 4 }|
|{ "a": 2, "c": 4 }|
+------------------+
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df.select(F.json_tuple(df.data,'a','b','c','d')).show()
+----+----+----+----+
|  c0|  c1|  c2|  c3|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|null|null|
|null|   3|null|   4|
|   2|null|   4|null|
+----+----+----+----+

>>> from pyspark.sql.types import *
>>> schema = StructType([StructField("a", StringType()),StructField("b", StringType()),StructField("c",StringType()),StructField("d", StringType())])
>>> df.select(F.from_json(df.data,schema).alias('data')).select(F.col('data.*')).show()
+----+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|   d|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|null|null|
|null|   3|null|   4|
|   2|null|   4|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: unfortunately no, there is a possibilty of new json keys

Comment: so, whenever a new key comes, we got to transform the dataframe to add that key as column ?

Comment: yes.. the idea is to generate columns for dataframe arriving in a certain window period..

Answer (score 1):

When you have a dynamic JSON column inside your Pyspark Dataframe, you can use below code to explode it's fields to columns

```
df2 = df.withColumn('columnx', udf_transform_tojsonstring(df.columnx))

columnx_jsonDF = spark.read.json(df2.rdd.map(lambda row: row.columnx)).drop('_corrupt_record')

df3 = df2.withColumn('columnx', from_json(col('columnx'),columnx_jsonDF.schema))
for c in set(columnx_jsonDF.columns):
    df3 = df3.withColumn(f'columnx_{c}',df2[f'columnx.`{c}`'])
```

explanation:
First we use a UDF to transform our column into a valid JSON string (if it's not already done)
In line 3 we read our column as JSON Dataframe (with inferred schema)

then we read `columnx` again with `from_json()` function, passing `columnx_jsonDF` schema to it

finally we add a column in the main Dataframe for each key inside our JSON Column

This works if we don't know the JSON fields in advance and yet, need to explode it's columns

Answer (score -1):

I guess, you don't need to do much.  For e.g.

```
Bala:~:$ cat myjson.json 
{ "a": 1, "b": 2 }
{ "b": 3, "d": 4 }
{ "a": 2, "c": 4 }

>>> df = sqlContext.sql("select * from json.`/Users/Bala/myjson.json`")
>>> df.show()
+----+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|   d|
+----+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|null|null|
|null|   3|null|   4|
|   2|null|   4|null|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: thanks for the response, however my case is structured streaming sir